# $f(x) $ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ (algebraic element) over $\mathbb Q$ , let $b=f'(a) \in \mathbb Q(a)$ , then is $\mathbb Q(a)=\mathbb Q(b)$?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $a \in \mathbb C$ be algebraic over $\mathbb Q$ , let $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb Q$ , let $b=f'(a) \in \mathbb Q(a)=\mathbb Q[a]$ , then is it true that $\mathbb Q(a)=\mathbb Q(b)$ ?

Comment: @Transcendental : The smallest " subfield " .. but since $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$ , the smallest subring and subfield are the same anyway

Comment: @Trancendental $\Bbb Q(a)$ is the smallest subfield, $\Bbb Q[a]$ is the smallest subring, but the notation makes sense even if $a\notin \Bbb C$.

Comment: @Arthur But as $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, any algebraic element $a$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be identified with an element of $\mathbb{C}$, no?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Anything algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, sure.  But you can also use this notation for something like a variable $x$ so that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is the polynomial ring and $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is the field of rational functions.  I think this is what Arthur was getting at.  Correct me if I'm wrong, Arthur.

Comment: @JoshKeneda Ok, that makes sense (even though the particular case of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ can be obtained as the extension by an arbitrary transcendental number...)

Comment: @JoshKeneda That's exactly what I meant. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a reason for suspecting that this might be true?

Comment: Even it's not true, I'd be interested in hearing how someone generates a counter-example.

Answer (score 24):

The answer seems to be no.

Cyclotomic fields are great (counter-)examples.  Take $a$ to be a primitive $24$th root of unity.  Its minimal polynomial is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{24}=x^8-x^4+1$.

Now $b=8a^7-4a^3$.  Sage helpfully tells us that the minimal polynomial of $b$ is $x^4+2304$.   Hence $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ don't have the same degree over $\mathbb{Q}$, and cannot be equal.

Comment: I know my first thought after I read any question is "Well, does it work for the 24th roots of unity"? :)

Answer (score 12):

Here is a hand calculation that can be used to replace
the Sage calculation in Plamondon's answer.

Since $a$ is a primitive 24th root of unity,
the number $a^5$ is also a primitive 24th root of unity
and there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb Q[a]$
such that $\sigma(a) = a^5\;(\neq a)$. Since $b = 8a^7-4a^3$ we have

$\sigma(b) = 8\sigma(a)^7-4\sigma(a)^3 = 8a^{35}-4a^{15} =
{\mathbf{8a^{11}-4a^{15}}}$.

Since $a$ is a solution to $x^8-x^4+1=0$, we have
$a^8=a^4-1$, which can help reduce expressions
involving powers of $a$. Using this we find

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\sigma(b)&=8a^{11}-4a^{15}\\
&=(4a^{11}+4a^{11})-4a^{15}\\
&=(4a^3(a^8)+4a^{11})-4a^7(a^8)\\
&=(4a^3(a^4-1) + 4a^{11})-4a^7(a^4-1)\\
&=8a^7-4a^3=b.
\end{array}
$$

The automorphism $\sigma$ fixes $b$, hence also fixes $\mathbb Q[b]$,
but $\sigma$ moves $a$. This proves that $a\notin \mathbb Q[b]$.

Answer (score 5):

I've been thinking about this for some time and while this is only a partial answer, perhaps someone can take this further.

Since $b=f'(a)$, we have that $\big(\mathbb{Q}(b)\big)(a)=\mathbb{Q}(a)$, which implies that the chain of inclusions $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(b) \subset \mathbb{Q}(a)$ is also a tower. Therefore, by the tower formula (in the obvious notation):

$$\deg(a)=\deg(b)\cdot \deg(a:b)$$

Now, suppose $a$ were prime. There are two possibilities:

- $\deg(b)=1$

In this case, $b \in \mathbb{Q}$, so $p(x)=f'(x) - b \in \mathbb{Q}(x)$. But then $f(x)$ is not minimal for $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, because $p(x)$ is also monic and its degree is less than $f$ (assuming that $\deg(f)>1$; otherwise the question is trivial anyway). This is a contradiction.

- $\deg(a:b)=1$

In this case, $a$ is a rational multiple of $b$, so indeed $\mathbb{Q}(a)=\mathbb{Q}(b)$.

> Hence, if there is a counterexample, then $a$ may not have prime degree.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that your reasoning for $deg(b)\neq 1$ applies no matter what $a$ is.  That is, $deg(b)>1$ whether or not $a$ has prime degree.